# VHDL - ModelSim testbench simulation freezes when sending "run"

Tags: io, vhdl, modelsim

I have a problem regarding a testbench I am developing for an hardware butterfly algorithm for calculating the Fourier transform.

What I'm attempting to do is reading a series of input data files (32-bit vectors) and writing the output in some other output files.

The input files are Ar.txt, Ai.txt, Br.txt, Bi.txt, Wr.txt and Wi.txt.

The output files are Ar_OUT_TB.txt, Ai_OUT_TB.txt, Br_OUT_TB.txt, Bi_OUT_TB.txt.

But when I try to simulate with ModelSim, the program simply freezes: I can still do some stuff, like opening another project/file etc., but there's no waveform showing, and also the command line is missing. I also tried to simulate an older VHDL project of mine and it did simulate, so I guess the problem is within this code.

These are the main processes (EDIT: I'm also adding the rest of the code, for understanding):

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
USE IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
USE STD.TEXTIO.ALL;

ENTITY BUTTERFLY_TESTBENCH IS
END BUTTERFLY_TESTBENCH;

ARCHITECTURE DEVICE OF BUTTERFLY_TESTBENCH IS

COMPONENT progetto_butterfly
        GENERIC(N_IN, N_OUT: INTEGER := 32;
                  N_BUSES: INTEGER := 63);
        PORT(START, CLK, MAIN_RST_N: IN STD_LOGIC;
              DATA_IN, Wr_IN, Wi_IN: IN SIGNED(N_IN-1 DOWNTO 0);
              DATA_OUT: OUT SIGNED(N_IN-1 DOWNTO 0);
              DONE: OUT STD_LOGIC);

END COMPONENT;

CONSTANT N_IN: INTEGER := 32;
CONSTANT N_OUT: INTEGER := 32;

SIGNAL TEST_DATA_IN, TEST_Wr_IN, TEST_Wi_IN: SIGNED(N_IN-1 DOWNTO 0);
SIGNAL TEST_OUTPUT: SIGNED(N_OUT-1 DOWNTO 0);
SIGNAL CLK: STD_LOGIC;
SIGNAL TEST_START, TEST_RST, TEST_DONE: STD_LOGIC;

FILE Ar_IN_FILE: TEXT OPEN READ_MODE IS "Ar.txt";
FILE Ai_IN_FILE: TEXT OPEN READ_MODE IS "Ai.txt";
FILE Br_IN_FILE: TEXT OPEN READ_MODE IS "Br.txt";
FILE Bi_IN_FILE: TEXT OPEN READ_MODE IS "Bi.txt";
FILE WR_FILE: TEXT OPEN READ_MODE IS "Wr.txt";
FILE WI_FILE: TEXT OPEN READ_MODE IS "Wi.txt";
FILE Ar_OUT: TEXT OPEN WRITE_MODE IS "Ar_OUT_TB.txt";
FILE Ai_OUT: TEXT OPEN WRITE_MODE IS "Ai_OUT_TB.txt";
FILE Br_OUT: TEXT OPEN WRITE_MODE IS "Br_OUT_TB.txt";
FILE Bi_OUT: TEXT OPEN WRITE_MODE IS "Bi_OUT_TB.txt";

BEGIN

    BUTTERFLY_TEST_COMPONENT: progetto_butterfly PORT MAP(START => TEST_START, CLK => CLK, MAIN_RST_N => TEST_RST, 
                                                                            DATA_IN => TEST_DATA_IN, Wr_IN => TEST_Wr_IN, Wi_IN => TEST_Wi_IN,
                                                                            DATA_OUT => TEST_OUTPUT, DONE => TEST_DONE);``

DATA_IN_PROCESS: PROCESS
VARIABLE DATA_BUFFER: LINE;
VARIABLE DATA_STIMULUS: BIT_VECTOR(N_IN-1 DOWNTO 0);
BEGIN
    IF NOT (ENDFILE(Br_IN_FILE)) THEN
        IF(TEST_START = '1' AND TEST_RST = '1') THEN
            READLINE(Br_IN_FILE,DATA_BUFFER);
            READ(DATA_BUFFER,DATA_STIMULUS);
            TEST_DATA_IN <= SIGNED(TO_STDLOGICVECTOR(DATA_STIMULUS));
            WAIT UNTIL CLK'EVENT AND CLK = '1';
            READLINE(Bi_IN_FILE,DATA_BUFFER);
            READ(DATA_BUFFER,DATA_STIMULUS);
            TEST_DATA_IN <= SIGNED(TO_STDLOGICVECTOR(DATA_STIMULUS));
            WAIT UNTIL RISING_EDGE(CLK);
            READLINE(Ar_IN_FILE,DATA_BUFFER);
            READ(DATA_BUFFER,DATA_STIMULUS);
            TEST_DATA_IN <= SIGNED(TO_STDLOGICVECTOR(DATA_STIMULUS));
            WAIT UNTIL RISING_EDGE(CLK);
            READLINE(Ai_IN_FILE,DATA_BUFFER);
            READ(DATA_BUFFER,DATA_STIMULUS);
            TEST_DATA_IN <= SIGNED(TO_STDLOGICVECTOR(DATA_STIMULUS));
            WAIT FOR 12 ns;
        ELSE
            TEST_DATA_IN <= (OTHERS => '0');
        END IF;
    END IF;
END PROCESS;

WR_PROCESS: PROCESS
VARIABLE wr_buf: LINE;
VARIABLE WR_STIMULUS: BIT_VECTOR(N_IN-1 DOWNTO 0);
BEGIN
        WHILE NOT (ENDFILE(WR_FILE)) LOOP
            IF(TEST_START = '1' AND TEST_RST = '1') THEN
                READLINE(WR_FILE,wr_buf);
                READ(wr_buf,WR_STIMULUS);
                TEST_Wr_IN <= SIGNED(TO_STDLOGICVECTOR(WR_STIMULUS));
                WAIT FOR 20 ns;
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
END PROCESS;

WRITING_PROCESS: PROCESS
VARIABLE  STRING_LINE: STRING(N_OUT DOWNTO 1);
VARIABLE  OUT_LINE: LINE;
VARIABLE  I: INTEGER;
BEGIN
    WAIT FOR 12 ns;
    WHILE (TEST_START = '1' AND TEST_RST = '1') LOOP
        FOR I IN N_OUT-1 DOWNTO 0 LOOP
            IF(TEST_OUTPUT(I) = '0') THEN
                STRING_LINE(I+1) := '0';
            ELSE
                STRING_LINE(I+1) := '1';
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
        WRITE(OUT_LINE,STRING_LINE);
        WRITELINE(Br_OUT,OUT_LINE);
        WAIT UNTIL RISING_EDGE(CLK);
        FOR I IN N_OUT-1 DOWNTO 0 LOOP
            IF(TEST_OUTPUT(I) = '0') THEN
                STRING_LINE(I+1) := '0';
            ELSE
                STRING_LINE(I+1) := '1';
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
        WRITE(OUT_LINE,STRING_LINE);
        WRITELINE(Bi_OUT,OUT_LINE);
        WAIT UNTIL RISING_EDGE(CLK);
        FOR I IN N_OUT-1 DOWNTO 0 LOOP
            IF(TEST_OUTPUT(I) = '0') THEN
                STRING_LINE(I+1) := '0';
            ELSE
                STRING_LINE(I+1) := '1';
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
        WRITE(OUT_LINE,STRING_LINE);
        WRITELINE(Ar_OUT,OUT_LINE);
        WAIT UNTIL RISING_EDGE(CLK);
        FOR I IN N_OUT-1 DOWNTO 0 LOOP
            IF(TEST_OUTPUT(I) = '0') THEN
                STRING_LINE(I+1) := '0';
            ELSE
                STRING_LINE(I+1) := '1';
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
        WRITE(OUT_LINE,STRING_LINE);
        WRITELINE(Ai_OUT,OUT_LINE);
    END LOOP;
END PROCESS;
    CLK_PROCESS: PROCESS
    BEGIN
        CLK <= '1';
        WAIT FOR 2 ns;
        CLK <= '0';
        WAIT FOR 2 ns;
    END PROCESS;

    TEST_RST <= '0', '1' AFTER 2 ns;
    TEST_START <= '0', '1' AFTER 3 ns;

END ARCHITECTURE;
```

Is something done wrong? I can't see what I'm missing.

Comment: There are two things that stop an error free simulation in VHDL.  You run out of scheduled events in all the driver's projected output waveforms and you advance simulation time to now'high or you run up against now'high (and that can take a while). A run command in Modelsim can be supplied with an execution time to run for a shorter interval. You don't show your entire model, particularly declarations. It's not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I added the rest of the code. As for the "now'high", can you explain me what do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `DATA_IN_PROCESS` process is an infinite loop. As long as as the condition `TEST_START = '1' AND TEST_RST = '1'` is not met, the process keeps on running, without incrementing simulated time. It eats up *simulator* time and *simuated* time does not increase.

Solve this by adding `WAIT UNTIL RISING_EDGE(CLK);` in the `else` clause.

Other problems with your code are listed here: http://www.sigasi.com/vhdl-code-check?ID=27869561

Comment: Yep, that was it. I removed both the WHILE statement and the IF statement as well. Now it runs! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your processes either need a sensitivity list or a `WAIT` statement.

Comment: I thought that in a testbench a sentivity list wasn't required. As for the WAIT statement, what should I wait for? The clock? In which point of the process? At the very beginning?

Comment: A process that lacks a sensitivity list and/or a wait statement would be required to execute its inner statements over and over again in no time. This is what your simulator is basically trying to do as per your request.

Comment: All processes have a `wait` statement. But they should have a `wait` statement in _every_ branch.

Answer (score 0):

After building an MVCe from your example I found that it appears an input file you're reading is too short, revealing faults in two of your processes (data_in_process and wr_process).

```
library ieee;
use std.textio.all;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity sometb is
end entity;

architecture foo of sometb is
    constant n_in: integer := 8;
    signal test_start:  std_logic := '1';
    signal test_rst:    std_logic := '1';
    file br_in_file: text open READ_MODE is "Br.txt";
    signal test_data_in:    signed(n_in - 1 downto 0);
    signal clk:     std_logic := '0';
    file bi_in_file: text open READ_MODE is "Bi.txt";
    file ar_in_file: text open READ_MODE is "Ar.txt";
    file ai_in_file: text open READ_MODE is "Ai.txt";
    file wr_file:    text open READ_MODE is "Wr.txt";
    signal test_wr_in:      signed(n_in - 1 downto 0);
    constant n_out: integer:= 8;
    signal test_output: std_logic_vector(n_out - 1 downto 0);
    file br_out:    text open WRITE_MODE is "Br_OUT_TB.txt";
    file bi_out:    text open WRITE_MODE is "Bi_OUT_TB.txt";
    file ar_out:    text open WRITE_MODE is "Ar_OUT_TB.txt";
    file ai_out:    text open WRITE_MODE is "Bi_OUT_TB.txt";
begin
CLOCK:
    process
    begin
        wait for 6 ns;
        clk <= not clk;
    end process;
data_in_process:
    process
        variable data_buffer: line;
        variable data_stimulus: bit_vector(n_in-1 downto 0);
    begin
        if not endfile(br_in_file) then
            if test_start = '1' and test_rst = '1'  then
                readline(br_in_file,data_buffer);
                read(data_buffer,data_stimulus);
                test_data_in <= signed(to_stdlogicvector(data_stimulus));
                wait until clk'event and clk = '1';
                readline(bi_in_file,data_buffer);
                read(data_buffer,data_stimulus);
                test_data_in <= signed(to_stdlogicvector(data_stimulus));
                wait until rising_edge(clk);
                readline(ar_in_file,data_buffer);
                read(data_buffer,data_stimulus);
                test_data_in <= signed(to_stdlogicvector(data_stimulus));
                wait until rising_edge(clk);
                readline(ai_in_file,data_buffer);
                read(data_buffer,data_stimulus);
                test_data_in <= signed(to_stdlogicvector(data_stimulus));
                wait for 12 ns;
            else
                test_data_in <= (others => '0');
            end if;
        end if;
        wait until rising_edge(clk); -- added for endfile
    end process;

wr_process:
    process
        variable wr_buf: line;
        variable wr_stimulus: bit_vector(n_in-1 downto 0);
    begin
        while not endfile(wr_file) loop
            if test_start = '1' and test_rst = '1' then
                readline(wr_file,wr_buf);
                read(wr_buf,wr_stimulus);
                test_wr_in <= signed(to_stdlogicvector(wr_stimulus));
                wait for 20 ns;
            end if;
        end loop;
        wait for 20 ns; -- added for when endfile(wr_file) is TRUE.
    end process;

writing_process: 
    process
        variable  string_line: string(n_out downto 1);
        variable  out_line: line;
--        variable  i: integer;  -- the following are not my i
    begin
        wait for 12 ns;
        while test_start = '1' and test_rst = '1' loop
            for i in test_output'range loop -- n_out-1 downto 0 loop
                if test_output(i) = '0' then
                    string_line(i + 1) := '0';
                else
                    string_line(i + 1) := '1';
                end if;
            end loop;
            write(out_line, string_line);
            writeline(br_out, out_line);
            wait until rising_edge(clk);
            for i in test_output'range loop -- n_out-1 downto 0 loop
                if test_output(i) = '0' then
                    string_line(i + 1) := '0';
                else
                    string_line(i + 1) := '1';
                end if;
            end loop;
            write(out_line,string_line);
            writeline(bi_out,out_line);
            wait until rising_edge(clk);
            for i in test_output'range loop -- n_out-1 downto 0 loop
                if test_output(i) = '0'  then
                    string_line(i+1) := '0';
                else
                    string_line(i+1) := '1';
                end if;
            end loop;
            write(out_line,string_line);
            writeline(ar_out,out_line);
            wait until rising_edge(clk);
            for i in test_output'range loop -- n_out-1 downto 0 loop
                if test_output(i) = '0' then
                    string_line(i+1) := '0';
                else
                    string_line(i+1) := '1';
                end if;
            end loop;
            write(out_line,string_line);
            writeline(ai_out,out_line);
        end loop;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

I added

```
        wait until rising_edge(clk); -- added for endfile
```

before the end of the process in data_in_process, otherwise it would loop without suspending if END_FILE(br_in_file) is TRUE.  (And you should really have a test or test that covers all your inputs).

I added

```
        wait for 20 ns; -- added for when endfile(wr_file) is TRUE.
```

to wr_process for the same reason.

The changes to writing_process were used to discover a working range for the test_output signal.  Note the the process declarative item for variable i can be removed, it's not used.  (The i there is not the i in the loop constants).

I found the problems with the input files by in a UNIX environment (OS X) touching the input files which creates them with a zero length (after insuring my VHDL simulator would complain if they don't exist).

Comment: After choosing the break option, modelsim shows me that the simulation breaks at line 102, which is the end of the endfile loop of the WI_PROCESS. I added a WAIT statement (just the WAIT) just after the end of the loop. Is it correlated to what you suggested about the lenght of the input file? It still seems a bit odd to me though: for debugging purposes I made sure that all files had just 1 line, representing my input data (1 line for Ar, 1 for Ai, etc). How is it possible?